# Why does the Component Designer generate a service installer object that it does not (appear to) use?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, service, installation

Following the steps detailed in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx#Y684, I have created a Windows service which I have successfully installed and tested. But I am puzzled by something in the components used to install the service.

Installation of the service is accomplished by a designer-generated `ProjectInstaller` class, shown below. This class is used by `installutil.exe` (in .NET Framework) to install the service and its associated service process. The designer-generated code creates two installer objects: `MyServiceInstaller` for the service, and `MyServiceProcessInstaller` for the service process, to be used by `installutil.exe` at installation time. However, it inserts only the latter into the `Installers` collection.

So how does the service itself get installed? Is there a "default service" for the service process, if no services are explicitly installed along with the service process?

**CODE:**

(If you experiment with this, you will find that the Designer actually creates this class using two partial-classes. I have consolidated these into a single class for simplicity.)

```
namespace MyService
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
         /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.MyServiceProcessInstaller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
            this.MyServiceInstaller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
            // 
            // MyServiceProcessInstaller
            // 
            this.MyServiceProcessInstaller.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            this.MyServiceProcessInstaller.Password = null;
            this.MyServiceProcessInstaller.Username = null;
            // 
            // MyServiceInstaller
            // 
            this.MyServiceInstaller.ServiceName = "MyService";
            // 
            // ProjectInstaller
            // 
            this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
            // *** Expected here:  this.MyServiceInstaller,
            this.MyServiceProcessInstaller});
        }

        private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller MyServiceProcessInstaller;
        private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller MyServiceInstaller;
    }
}
```

Comment: I vaguely recall reading that one of these is used by `installutil` and the other is used if you build a Windows Installer. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @Joe - Thanks,  I'll have a look at that as a possiblity.

Comment: Does this explain? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Jacob - Thanks. Unfortunately, the article leaves me even more puzzled because it says (see Remarks section): "set the installation properties for the service using the **ServiceProcessInstaller** and **ServiceInstaller** instances, and add the instances to the **Installers** collection." This is exactly what I would expect. However, the designer-generated code adds only the **ServiceProcessInstaller** to the **Installers** collection. Hence my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **ServiceInstaller** does need to be added to the collection of Installers.  I followed the same steps described in the article and it came out correctly:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
   this.serviceProcessInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
   this.serviceInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
   // 
   // serviceProcessInstaller1
   // 
   this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
   this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = null;
   // 
   // serviceInstaller1
   // 
   this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "Service1";
   // 
   // ProjectInstaller
   // 
   this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
      this.serviceProcessInstaller1,
      this.serviceInstaller1});

}
```

Comment: Sorry for slow reply. Very busy. As an exercise, I repeated the prescribed steps for creating a service, and got the expected result (i.e. same as yours). However, I know that when I did this originally, I definitely only got an installer for the service process, not the service itself, and I did not hack on the designer-generated code. I then installed it, and the service ran just fine. So I think there are cases where the designer behaves as I described in my question, but it isn't worth spending any any more time on it at this point. Thanks for looking into this.